# htaccess redirect if url doesn't contain some string as subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I´m working with a django website and I need to do a kind of "if else" statement in the htaccess file.

if the person goes to http://itcvertebralcuritiba.com.br/blog, i want to redirect to the server subdirectory public_html/blog and ignore all the rest of the code inside htaccess file, because it installs django and change the paths.

this is the current htaccess file: (it installs django´s stuff)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(dispatch\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itccuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.itccuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "itcvertebralcuritiba\.com\.br" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itcvertebralcuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.itcvertebralcuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/itcvertebralcuritiba\.com\.br" [R=301,L]
```

I tried doing this to redirect:
--these 3 lines below is what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(dispatch\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itccuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.itccuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "itcvertebralcuritiba\.com\.br" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itcvertebralcuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.itcvertebralcuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/itcvertebralcuritiba\.com\.br" [R=301,L]
```

but it did not work, it redirects but with a 500 error (internal server error).

Can anyone help me? thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you want those rules with the `R=301` rules **first**. You want your redirects to happen before your internal rewrites.

The second thing is your rule loops. The rewrite engine executes all the rules until the URI stops changing. In your case, you keep rewriting to the same place: `/blog/index.php`, even if the request is *already* `/blog/index.php`. Try adding a few conditions to prevent the looping.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itccuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.itccuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "itcvertebralcuritiba\.com\.br" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^itcvertebralcuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.itcvertebralcuritiba\.pre\-hw44\.webservidor\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/itcvertebralcuritiba\.com\.br" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(dispatch\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hello Jon Lin, thanks very much for your reply. I tried to  use your code but unfortunately this redirect to http://itcvertebralcuritiba.com.br/blog/ is not working, instead it gives another 500 error (internal server error).

Comment: The problem is probably with the part that is meant to redirect to http://itcvertebralcuritiba.com.br/blog/ :(